# SQL Sum() Function and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, inner-join

TWO TABLES

ORDER_TABLE:

```
ORDER_ID | TARGET_QTY | 
-----------------------
1        |    50     
2        |    100  
3        |    200
```

ALLOC_TABLE:

```
ORDER_ID | TARGET_QTY |
-----------------------
1        |         50  
2        |         20  
2        |         30  
3        |        200
```

I want to return ORDER_TABLE.ORDER_ID's where the SUM(ALLOC_TABLE.TARGET_QTY) for an order ID is < ORDER_TABLE.TARGET_QTY. Ex. of desired output below:

```
ORDER_ID | 
---------
2
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
at.ORDER_ID
FROM
    ALLOC_TABLE at
    JOIN ORDER_TABLE ot ON at.ORDER_ID = ot.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY
    at.ORDER_ID, ot.TARGET_QTY
HAVING
    SUM(at.TARGET_QTY) < ot.TARGET_QTY
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pls

```
SELECT  at.ORDER_ID
FROM   ALLOC_TABLE at
full outer JOIN ORDER_TABLE ot ON at.ORDER_ID = ot.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY at.ORDER_ID
HAVING SUM(at.TARGET_QTY) < ot.TARGET_QTY
```